# I can't use image() and rect() in the draw() method in JavaScriptMode

Tags: processing

I can't seem to use image() and rect() together in the draw() method in JavaScriptMode. When I try to run the code the sketch does nothing. It's supposed to print out a background of green circles with a white rectangle in the middle. I have seen this done perfectly in the sketches of other people, so I am not sure what is the case with this. I am not using createShape() here (I understand that does not yet work in JavaScriptMode.

Here is my code:

```java
PImage image;
void setup() {
  size(400,400);
  image = loadImage("green-circles-wallpaper-4893-5151-hd-wallpapers.jpg");
}
void draw() {
  image(image,0,0,width,height);
  rect(100,100,200,200);
}
```

I am trying to draw a green circle.

Comment: What exactly does this code do? What do you see when you run it? What do you expect to see?

Comment: It's supposed to print out a background of green circles with a white rectangle in the middle.

Comment: And what do you see instead?

Comment: What image are you using? (I doubt that would be the issue, but might as well rule it out.)

Comment: I see nothing. Nothing is done at all.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript mode is more finicky when it comes to what you name your variables. Specifically, you can't name a variable the same thing as a function.

Your `image` variable is interfering with the `image()` function, since they have the same name. To fix your problem, just rename your `image` variable to something like `myImage` instead.

```
PImage myImage;
void setup() {
  size(400,400);
  myImage = loadImage("green-circles-wallpaper-4893-5151-hd-wallpapers.jpg");
}
void draw() {
  image(myImage,0,0,width,height);
  rect(100,100,200,200);
}
```

You should also get into the habit of checking the JavaScript console for errors. In most browsers, you can bring up the developer tools be pressing the `F12` key. There you'll find a console tab, and any errors you're getting will show up there. Your code generates an error that says `"Uncaught TypeError: image is not a function"` which makes sense, since you've overwritten the `image()` function with your `image` variable.

This is covered in [the Processing.js documentation](http://processingjs.org/articles/p5QuickStart.html#variablenamingcare):

> Processing.js requires more care with variable naming than Processing
>
> One of the powerful features of JavaScript is its dynamic, typeless nature. Where typed languages like Java, and therefore Processing, can reuse names without fear of ambiguity (e.g., method overloading), Processing.js cannot. Without getting into the inner-workings of JavaScript, the best advice for Processing developers is to not use function/class/etc. names from Processing as variable names. For example, a variable named line might seem reasonable, but it will cause issues with the similarly named line() function built-into Processing and Processing.js. This is equally true for built-in functions and functions you create. A good rule- of-thumb is: avoid having a variable foo in the same sketch as a function foo();.